# Find bijection $\phi:[n]\times S_{n-1}\to S_n$ and conclude that $\vert S_n\vert = n!$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations, symmetric-groups

$[n] = \{1,...,n\}$
I am struggling with finding the bijection.

$\underline{\text{Assume } \mathbf{n=3:}}$

Than we have $A:=[n]\times S_{n-1} = \{(1,\pi_1), (2,\pi_1),(3,\pi_1),(1,\pi_2), (2,\pi_2),(3,\pi_2)\}$,
with $\pi_1 = id$ and $\pi_2 = (12)$

$S_3 = \{(123), (12)(3), (13)(2), (23)(1), (132), id\}$

So we are looking for some $\phi:A\to S_3$. The mapping for $a\in A \mapsto \sigma\in S_3$ is not obvious to me.

Has someone a hint?

The conclusion should be easy if the bijection is found.

**Edit:**
Due to your hints and further research I found
$\phi:[n]\times S_{n-1}\to S_n, (i,\pi_j)\mapsto \pi_j\circ (in)$, $i\in[n], j\in [n-1]$

My current status on $\phi^{-1}$ is:
$\phi^{-1}:S_n\to [n]\times S_{n-1}, \pi \mapsto (\pi^{-1}(n), ???)$

I am still struggling with $\phi^{-1}$. Does someone has a hint?

Comment: Write an element of $S_n$ in one-line notation, namely $w\in S_n$ is written as $w(1)w(2)\dotsb w(n)$. Now how would you get elements of $S_n$ in one-line notation from elements of $S_{n-1}$ in one-line notation?

Comment: It's an odd question to me because I presume it assumes you know that $|S_{n}| = (n-1)!$? Otherwise how could you make your explicit bijection? But then it is pretty obvious anyway. So perhaps you are supposed to use a proof of induction on $n$.

Comment: @DerekLuna I don't understand your comment. The bijection is exactly what enables you to make the induction.

Comment: I don't understand yours either. Perhaps you can answer the question so I can see what you mean. I don't agree this is "exactly" what enables one to make the induction. There are plenty of other (better, logical) ways to find that $|S_{n}| = n!$ without using bijections. It seems like a contrived problem to me which is what I was getting at.

Comment: You have by the bijection gives us the induction step $$ \vert S_{n+1}\vert =\vert S_n \times [n+1]\vert =\vert S_n \vert \cdot \vert [n+1]\vert =n!\cdot (n+1)=(n+1)!.$$

Comment: @DerekLuna Any and all algebro-combinatorial arguments that lead to the conclusion that $|\Sigma_n|=n!$ ultimately rely on bijections, be it even in a very implicit and obviated manner.

Comment: Well, the notion of contrieved is quite subjective. I find this way of argueing rather natural.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ You can reframe an argument to be the "same" as another if you look deep enough, but I disagree it is reliant on them. I don't agree all of those types of arguments rely on bijections. Basically what you are saying is if the idea of a bijection didn't exist, you don't think there is a valid proof that there are n! permutations on $n$ symbols? In fact the very idea of $S_{n}$ relies on this..., a combinatorial problem.

Comment: @DerekLuna We see you would disagree, the whole point is that you would be wrong in doing so. Bijections are fundamental to any combinatorial argument that involves establishing relations for counting cardinalities. Agreed of course that there might be some variation in the methods one uses to derive such relations, but the fact that these bijections are always at work in the background is an inescapable fact, as much as you would want to disagree.

Comment: The idea of permutating elements has existed long before the idea of a bijection. I don't know why you are having difficulty understanding that the very idea of bijections and by extension $S_{n}$ relies on the aforementioned idea, not the other way around. To think that the problem of arranging elements relies on the idea of mapping elements from one set to the another is wrong and naive. One clearly predates the other, so how could it rely on it?

Comment: @DerekLuna As far as the point of view of the history of conceptual development of mathematical notions is concerned (permutations predating the notion of..), I would say you are right. What I meant to stress is a rather metaphysical reality, namely that bijections are operant (in the background at least) every single time one carries out a combinatorial argument in order to count objects and set up cardinal relations. Whether the one carrying out such an argument has reached the stage of conceptual maturity *(to be cont.)*

Comment: In the background does not mean reliant. One can frame it to be equivalent to this type of argumentation. I for one think this notion in sui is enough (logically correct, formal ) without calling upon these later ideas.

Comment: @DerekLuna *(cont.)* at which one can fully grap the general notion of bijection is not relevant to the point I was trying to make. I am not interested in "whether the idea of bijection didn't exist", for bijections themselves are an objective metaphysical reality, objective metaphysical immaterial invariant, unchanging entities, regardless whether humanity is or not at a a stage of mathematical maturity at which to be able to properly introduce and formalise these general objects in set theory and subsequent combinatorial arguments.

Comment: You aren't understanding what I am saying either. To clarify, what I am saying is the following: on a nontrivial level, the idea of permutating elements is distinct from taking a bijection. Meaning, I would say that two separate things are going on. It doesn't matter if you can reframe it to make sense as a problem involving a bijection is my point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116236/discussion-between--and-derek-luna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permutation $\pi$ of $S_n$, which is a bijective map from $[n]$ to $[n]$, is completely characterized by specifying $\pi(i)$ for all $i\in[n]$. The idea is that we can break this into two parts, (1) the specification of $\pi(n)$, and (2) the specification of $\pi(i)$ for $i\in[n-1]$. If $\pi(n)=n$ then $\pi$ restricted to $[n-1]$ is just an element of $S_{n-1}$. On the other hand if $\pi(n)=j\ne n$, then $\pi(i)\ne j$ for any $i\in[n-1]$ but $\pi(k)=n$ for some $k\in[n-1]$. So $\pi$ restricted to $[n-1]$ is a bijective map from $[n-1]$ to $[n]\setminus\{j\}$, which is not so different from a bijective map from $[n-1]$ to $[n-1]$, that is, from an element of $S_{n-1}$. (Both are bijective maps between sets of size $n-1$.)

To realize a concrete bijection between these two kinds of bijective map, we send the map $\pi$, restricted to $[n-1]$, to an element of $S_{n-1}$ by composing $\pi$ with the swap $(jn)$. Note that composition with $(jn)$ is an involution: composing $\pi$ with $(jn)$ twice in succession gives $\pi$.

So for $\pi\in S_n$ use the map $\pi\mapsto(j,\pi\circ(jn))$, where $j=\pi(n)$ and $\pi\circ(jn)$ means the permutation $\pi$ is followed by the swap $(jn)$. The map $\pi\circ(jn)$ is here understood, by restricting to $[n-1]$, as an element of $S_{n-1}$, which is possible since it maps $n$ to itself. The definition of this map applies even when $j=n$ since then $(jn)$ is the identity permutation.

For the inverse, just use the fact that composition with $(jn)$ is an involution. Let $\rho\in S_{n-1}$. Then use the map $(j,\rho)\mapsto\rho\circ(jn)$. In this definition $\rho$ is understood as an element of $S_n$ that sends $n$ to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have $\pi_1 = \pmatrix{1 & 2\\ 1&2}$ and $\pi_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1}$ or as sequences of the images $\pi_1 = 12$ and $\pi_2=21$ without delimiters.

Rule: in $(i,\pi)$ write $n$ in the $i$th position of $\pi$. Here:

$(1,p_1) = 312$, $(2,p_1)=132$ and $(3,\pi_1)= 123$ or $(1,\pi_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 3&1&2}$, $(2,\pi_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 1&3&2}$ and $(3,\pi_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 1&2&3}$.
This demonstrates also  the general situation.

Comment: Why is $(1,\pi_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 3&1&2}$ and not $(1,\pi_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 3&2&1}$?

Comment: $\phi:[3]\times S_{2}\to S_3, (i,f_j) \mapsto \pi_l$, with $1\leq i\leq 3, 1\leq j\leq 2, 1\leq l\leq 6, \pi_l(i)=3$. With this I get for example $(1,f_1) = \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\\ 3&x&x}$. What is the condition for the 2nd and 3rd position in $\pi_l$?

Comment: Rule is above...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant way of recursively deriving the factorial expression for the order of the finite symmetric groups, but nevertheless let us attempt a suggestion.

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the map:
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi \colon \Sigma_{n+1} &\to [1, n+1] \times \Gamma\\
\Phi(\sigma)&=\left(\sigma(n+1), (n+1\ \sigma(n+1)) \circ \sigma\right),
\end{align*}$$
where $\Gamma=\mathrm{Stab}_{\Sigma_{n+1}}(n+1)$ is the subset (subgroup actually) of permutations of the *natural* interval $[1, n+1]$ which fix $n+1$, subset which is clearly isomorphic (as a group, even!) to $\Sigma_n$.

The map $\Phi$ is the bijection you are looking for.

Comment: thanks!  We dont know anything about groups (subgroups) but the definition of $S_n$. So considering this it is  a little hard to follow.

Comment: @WernerWerner You can for the time being ignore any occurrence of the word group in the above answer, it should still be readable. The syntagm ''two sets are isomorphic" simply means they are equipotent, i.e. there exists a bijection between them.